# How to get FunctionName from msg.data Signature in Solidity

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, abiencoderv2

Is it possible to decode the signature of a method from msg.data and get the Function name aside the parameters of the function using abi.decode? or any other way aside from using the ABI?

Answer (score 0):

There is no deterministic method to get the name of a function.
However, there are some projects that aim to collect common function names.(i.e. https://sig.eth.samczsun.com/)

Comment: Adding http://4byte.directory as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

In Solidity, you can't directly decode the function name from `msg.data` using native ABI functionalities. However, you can extract the function selector and compare it against known selectors to identify the function. Here's a modular Solidity example that demonstrates this approach:

##### Contract: FunctionSignatureDecoder

This contract holds a mapping of known function selectors to their corresponding function names.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract FunctionSignatureDecoder {
    mapping(bytes4 => string) public functionSelectors;

    constructor() {
        functionSelectors[bytes4(keccak256("set(uint256)"))] = "set(uint256)";
        functionSelectors[bytes4(keccak256("get()"))] = "get()";
    }

    function identifyFunction(bytes4 functionSelector) external view returns (string memory) {
        string memory functionName = functionSelectors[functionSelector];
        if (bytes(functionName).length == 0) {
            return "Unknown function";
        }
        return functionName;
    }
}
```

##### Contract: FunctionSignatureDecoderCaller

This contract calls `FunctionSignatureDecoder` to identify the function being invoked, which is kind of redundant since the function selector in `msg.data` corresponds with the `FunctionSignatureDecoderCaller` function being invoked.

```
contract FunctionSignatureDecoderCaller {
    FunctionSignatureDecoder immutable functionSignatureDecoder;

    constructor(FunctionSignatureDecoder _functionSignatureDecoder) {
        functionSignatureDecoder = _functionSignatureDecoder;
    }

    function set(uint256 _value) external view returns (string memory functionName) {
        bytes4 functionSelector = bytes4(msg.data[:4]);
        return functionSignatureDecoder.identifyFunction(functionSelector);
    }

    function get() external view returns (string memory functionName) {
        bytes4 functionSelector = bytes4(msg.data[:4]);
        return functionSignatureDecoder.identifyFunction(functionSelector);
    }
}
```

##### Important Considerations

- **Function Selector Collisions**: Function selectors are 4-byte hash segments, which could lead to collisions. It means two different functions might have the same selector, although the probability is low. Therefore, it's not 100% reliable to identify a function uniquely.
- **One-way Hash Function**: Keccak-256 is a one-way hash function. This implies that once you have the hash or the function selector (first 4 bytes of the hash), you can't reverse-engineer it to get the original function signature. Hence, you must know the function signatures in advance and map them to their corresponding selectors, as done in the `FunctionSignatureDecoder` contract.